# new lines, default font and size (open xml sdk)

Tags: c#, .net, openxml-sdk, openxml

What I need is to insert a new line at the end of a text.

I try with  `run.Append(**new Break()**);`
but this simulates to pressing (Shift+Enter) keys, and if I want a justified text the latest line autofits with lot of spaces between word and word...

And another problem I have is the default font and size in this *"Breaks"/"New Lines"*.
I try to "Appen" paragraph propierties in this run (wich contains the break)... but seems that is not allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `CarriageReturn` instead.

```
run.Append(new CarrigeReturn());
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.carriagereturn.aspx

Comment: Thanks!! It works great!! The only thing i still need to solve is the problem with the font and font-size... how can I specify it for the height of a blank space?

Comment: @Displaying, glad this worked for your immediate need.  Please ask a new question for the new font-size issue.  I don't know the answer off-hand.